# Unable to get the output wrapped within quotes

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

There are two items I'm trying to work with. One is `name` and another is `id`. I would like to get the items wrapped within `double quotes`and concatenated with `:`. However, I'm being unable to. Thanks for any help.

I have tried so far:

```
name = 'Mark'
idnum = 2134
print(name + " : " + str(idnum))
```

Output I'm having:

```
Mark : 2134
```

Output I would like to have:

```
"Mark" : "2134"   ##mind the quotes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[use string formatting](https://pyformat.info/)

```
name = 'Mark'
idnum = 2134
print('"{0}" : "{1}"'.format(name, str(idnum)))
#"Mark" : "2134"
```

Comment: Worth noting that the `0`, `1` and `str()` are all optional. `print('"{}" : "{}"'.format(name, idnum))` yields the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is close to what the csv module is good at, except that the delimiter can only be a single quote.

```
>>> import sys
>>> import csv
>>> wr = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter=":", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
>>> dummy = wr.writerow(('Mark', 1234))
"Mark":"1234"
>>>
```

It is certainly overkill for your current requirement, but it could help in a slighly more serious example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll keep that in mind. Provided plus one. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Well when you declare 
`name = 'Mark'`
you are declaring a `string` variable. If you want to add `""` try
`print("\"" +name + "\"" + " : " + str(idnum))`